# Парсинг markdown на python

Tags: python, вконтакте, markdown

Есть тексты постов, оформленные с использованием markdown, их необходимо перепостить в ВК массово. ВК не поддерживает markdown. Необходимо из текста убрать символы форматирования (** * # итд), а ссылки и картинки выделить, чтобы прикрепить их особым образом. Все это надо реализовать на питоне.

Я не нашел пакетов python, которые делали бы что-то похожее(только [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/))  , но он требует отдельной установки и является слишком большим проектом. Остальные markdown парсеры умеют только преобразовывать markdown в html.

**Собственно вопрос:**

Что более эффективно: markdown->html->my_format на готовых библиотеках или же самостоятельно распарсить markdown при помощи регулярок. Или есть иной способ, который мне не пришел в голову. Как грамотнее распарсить?

PS Почему спрашиваю - точно знаю, что html регулярками парсить точно не стоит, а про markdown никогда ничего не слышал

Comment: Ну вот сходу такой конвертер в `html` находится https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2

Comment: @CrazyElf в html конвертеров много, но вопрос в необходимости. Стоит ли использовать медленные и сложные регулярки или же гонять markdown в html, а уже потом парсить инфу